# Converging rail tracks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

When we look at parallel rail tracks, it appears to converge at a certain angle. Let us say the width of the tracks is d and the height of the eye is h. Assuming one stands in the middle of the tracks, what is the angle at which the tracks appear to converge at infinity?

Comment: This is an interesting problem that I've not really thought about before. Have you tried working out any of the geometry yourself?

Comment: Yes I did using a simplistic model. It turned out to be 2 arctan(d/2h) where d is the width of the tracks and h is the height of observation. Try it out :-)

Answer (score 2):

When your eyesight is exactly horizontal; i.e. the axis of the convex lens of the eye is parallel to the ground, for given distance $x$ sufficiently far away from the eye, the point of one of the rail tracks $(x,h,d/2)$ forms an image at the point $ (\frac{ld}{2x}, \frac{lh}{x})$ on the image plane at the back of the eye.  Here, $l$ is the distance between the image plane and the lens of the eye. (For the given fixed distance $x$, you are always straining your eye to adjust the focal length so that the image distance is $l$.) Thus $x$ parametrises a straight line which makes an angle $\tan^{-1}(d/2h)$, with the vertical axis on the image plane, and thus the total angle is $2 \tan^{-1}(d/2h)$. The configuration on the image plane is inverted, when the signal goes to the brain but this subtended angle, of course, remains the same.